# radio button tab sequencing

Tags: html, css

Default tab indexing is NOT working with radio buttons, working fine with any other HTML component e.g. checkbox, textbox etc.

Below basic code not working for radio button tab index but working fine with checkbox.

```
<div class="box">
  <input type="radio" name="rdgroup">H
  <input type="radio" name="rdgroup">E
  <input type="radio" name="rdgroup">L
</div>


<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckgroup">W
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckgroup">O
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckgroup">R
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wtyg7cLz/

Thank you :)

Comment: because of your radio button name are same so it considers as one control.

Comment: even if we remove "name" same behavior no sequence indexing https://jsfiddle.net/wtyg7cLz/1/

Comment: my friend doesn't remove the name just change the name of all radio buttons.

Comment: @PavanNagadiya yes main problem is it's no more radio group  https://jsfiddle.net/wtyg7cLz/2/

Answer (score 9):

Essentially a radio button is a group that functions as a single element since it retains only a single value. Tabbing to a radio group will bring you to the first item and then using the arrow keys you navigate within the group....

Answer (score 3):

When you assign same name to the ratio buttons, it treats you like a one control. However when you don't select anyone you can have a focus on first one and then use arrow button to select the one you want to.

> Focus can move to a radio group via: The Tab key An Access Key or
>   mnemonic targeting the label Activation of the label (through
>   Assistive Technology mechanism)
>
> The Tab key moves focus between radio button groups and other widgets.
>
> When focus is on the group and when no radio button is selected: Tab
>   key press moves focus to the first radio button in the group, but does
>   not select the radio button. Shift+Tab key press moves focus to the
>   last radio button in the group, but does not select the radio button.

Source: https://www.w3.org/wiki/RadioButton

Comment: Also, different name is not considering different control https://jsfiddle.net/wtyg7cLz/2/

Comment: @ahmad.ideveloper I can see its working moving focus on tab when given different names

Comment: yes it's considering, but it's NOT behaving as "radio group", no single selection now

Comment: @ahmad.ideveloper what do you mean by that? I don't understand.

Comment: the radio group is for single selection out of available options from the group, e.g. suppose you have **gender** male or female, so you must **choose one**, IF we remove group-name user can able to select both

Comment: @ahmad.ideveloper yes that is why you give the same name, but your question is when you move the focus you should be able to focus on next radio, that is not possible, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As **@Just Code** said:

> When you assign same name to the ratio buttons, it treats you like a one control. However when you don't select anyone you can have a focus on first one and then use arrow button to select the one you want to.

For radio buttons as a group if they have the same name then changing focus will work or navigate with arrow keys like (right, left, up, down).that is the default behavior of radio buttons, it is better to leave it as default. If you prefer tab control then i guess you have to implement it with javascript, because if you give them different name user can select all different radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <input type="radio" name="rdgroup" tabindex="1">H
  <input type="radio" name="rdgroup" tabindex="2">E
  <input type="radio" name="rdgroup" tabindex="3">L
</div>


<div class="box">
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckgroup">W
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckgroup">O
  <input type="checkbox" name="ckgroup">R
</div>
```

you could use the tabindex attribute to get a workaround after the first radio button element gets focused the user can then use the arrow keys (default) to select the desired option.

kindly check the below link for more details.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp